# I'm looking for a fantasy book about a princess with silver skin.

Tags: story-identification, books

Her family is murdered and she has to hide.  One of the big plot points of the book was about how the kingdom had no birds due to a curse being placed on it by one of her ancestors.  I can't remember her name, the name of any of the characters, or the title.

Comment: This seems quite vague...

Answer (score 8):

I believe you're looking for *[Avielle of Rhia](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1007276.Avielle_Of_Rhia)* by Dia Calhoun.

> With her silver skin and silver hair, fifteen-year-old Princess Avielle of Rhia resembles her Dredonian great-great grandmother who practiced evil magic. Everyone in Rhia expects Avielle to turn evil, too. Shunned by those around her, she feels unloved and unable to love others. In addition, she fears that Rhia will go to war with Dredonia, which suffers under the rule of evil wizard-priests: the Brethren of the Black Cloaks. They have placed impossible demands upon Rhia, but the king and queen have refused to acquiesce.
>
> One terrible night, the Brethren attack, killing the royal family and hundreds of others. Only Avielle escapes. She must keep her identity secret to avoid death from the enemy. While hiding among the common people, she learns that she has a magical gift for weaving. But will this gift, rooted in her Dredonian blood, lead Avielle to the same evil that possessed her great-great grandmother? Or will it help her free her people from further attacks?

A review by "Nicole N." further down the page mentions the lack of birds:

> Princess Avielle, silverskin and hair, scalloped forehead, and pointy-eared, fears that she will become like her great-great-grandmother, Queen Dolvoka, otherwise known as the "Cursed One" who sent the birds away from Rhia, and who happened to look exactly like Aveille.